# How can I conditionally redirect to https using mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I would like to redirect to https using mod_rewrite only if certain conditions are met:

If the URL does NOT contain the word 'administrator'
AND the URL DOES contain the string 'xyz' (in any part of the URL, including the querystring)

This does not seem to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xyz [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} xyz [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !administrator [NC]
ReWriteCond %{HTTPS} != on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Is the space after the equals sign meant to be there in your `%[HTTPS} != on` condition? It causes an internal server error for me due to how the directive is parsed.

Comment: @Tim: I guess not as *HTTPS* can only be `on` or `off`. Furthermore, the space separates the directive “parameters” and a literal space must be escaped with `\ ` or put into quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a coding solution as I could not get it to work with mod_rewrite. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !administrator
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} xyz
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Testing the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) in *THE_REQUEST* is easier as it contains both the path and query. But make sure your *xyz* is not part of the [method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1) or [HTTP version](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.1).